# Equations in finite subgroups of unitary groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, matrices, oa.operator-algebras

Let $n$ be an integer. Andreas Thom [mentioned](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34625/finite-subgroups-of-unitary-groups) that Camille Jordan showed that there exists some $m \in {\mathbb N}$ (depending on $n$), such that for any pair of $n \times n$-unitaries $u,v \in U(n)$ which generate a finite group, one has $[u^m,v^m] = 1_n$. In particular, there are two distinct words of length $\ell=2m $ over the alphabet $\{u,v\} $ that represent the same group element.

My question is

> what is known about how small such an $m_n$ or $\ell_n $ can be?

The connection with the Jordan-Schur Theorem is that if $G$ is a finite group generated by $u$ and $v$, and $H$ a normal abelian subgroup of index $m$, then $u^mH=H$ and $v^mH=H$ (since any group element raised to the order of the group is the identity) and so $u^m$ and $v^m$ belong to $H$, hence, $H$ being abelian, they commute. So if $[G:H]=m$ with $H$ abelian then we have such an $m$.

Comment: I guess you mean, for given $n$, what is the smallest $m_n\ge 1$ with this property? (Compute or at least estimate $m_n$?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bound on the index of an abelian subgroup in discrete subgroup of the euclidean group?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/176665/bound-on-the-index-of-an-abelian-subgroup-in-discrete-subgroup-of-the-euclidean)

Comment: OK, it's closely related anyway: first you consider $U(n)$ while the other question also considers $O(n)$. Second, you specify to a special case (two generators and their powers). Thom's answer to the linked question provides you a reasonable upper bound on $m_n$.

Comment: PS these provide upper bounds rather close to $n!$. Here the worse case could be closer to the exponent of the symmetric group (lcm of first $n$ integers), which seems to rather grow exponentially.

Comment: I would guess that something on the order $O(\exp(n))$ is enough (and tight). However, if it helps, there should be much shorter non-trivial words $w \in F_2$, such that $w(u,v)=1_n$ whenever $u,v$ generate a finite group.

Comment: @AndreasThom Oh yes that would help, see updated version of question.

Comment: So the question can be formulated as follows: let $K_n$ be the intersection of all kernels of all homomorphisms from the free group $F_2=<x,y>$ to finite subgroups of $U(n)$. Let $q_n$ be the smallest size of a nontrivial element in $K_n$. Can we have good estimates on $q_n$? (One can probably find elements in $K_n$ of the form $[x^m,y^m]$ with $m$ exponentially large w.r.t $n$, according to the previous discussion). In scholar language, $F_2/K_n$ is the free group in the variety generated by finite subgroups of $U(n)$, and the question is about its girth.

Comment: The shortest known identity for $Sym(n)$ is of length $\exp(C \log(n)^4 \log(\log(n)))$. I would expect that this is the crucial case, which dominates the estimates for the length of laws for all finite subgroups. There is no non-trivial known (at least to me) lower bound for the length of such an identity (be it for $Sym(n)$ or all finite subgroups of $U(n)$). The trivial lower bound is linear.

Comment: I think I can prove what I claimed in a few pages.

Comment: @AndreasThom I wonder if these words $w$ with $w(u,v)=1_n$ can be chosen so that $w(u,v)=1_n$ is equivalent to $x=y$ for two words (with no inverses being taken) of the same length $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen, any such equality $x=y$ would be a semigroup identity for $Sym(n)$. I do not think that those can be shorter than $C\exp(n)$, but I am not completely sure.